# Where can I find a package for "project looking Glass"? ("The Java desktop")

Tags: java, desktop-environments

I really really want to find this package. Because after I saw the [youtube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMWd1FOgr18) I realized it's just one of those things I must have done before I die.

[This tutorial](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-sun-looking-glass-desktop-environment-in-ubuntu.html) would be great if the repository were online.

My question is:

**Where can I find the file, and how can I install it without changing my current desktop?**

The project was called "project looking glass" and was released in 2007. It is now an "inactive open source project", according to [its Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Looking_Glass).

by using my answer I managed to make a boot able device and

I had an error while booting so I will ask that question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: A blast from the past! I'm in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This credit should be all on @takkat and @octavianDamiean.

@Takkat
He found [this ISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lg3d-livecd/) almost immediately after I posted this question! And he try to use Virtual VM, but it didn't work so we had to re think this problem.

I try to install the ISO on the ubuntu "start up disc creator" but it failed so I asked @octavianDamiean.
He said throw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30048/how-can-i-create-a-bootable-usb-disk-from-a-cd-image) question what I should do to boot from the ISO through a USB-stick.

Answer (score 4):

Found this link for some source and additional info: http://java.net/projects/lg3d/

You can get the software by using `subversion`

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Enter the command:

```
svn co https://svn.java.net/svn/lg3d~svn
```

Comment: He linked you to where you can get the source code which is the best thing one can provide for an abandoned project.

Comment: you mean the second best. the best is a package! :D

Comment: Be a man, build from source!

Comment: well that's plan B ;)
let's focus on the ISO!

Comment: I'm guessing that any package would be outdated and broken due to dependencies.