# How can I create a bootable USB disk from a CD image?

Tags: usb, live-cd

I have a bootable CD image that I would like to transfer to a USB stick, so that I can boot from it. The Startup-Disk creator doesn't support it. How can I make a bootable USB disk from it? The ISO is quite old so that might be a problem.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16277/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-from-a-iso-file

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-iso-to-usb-device/60430#60430

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [UNetbootin](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unetbootin)

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

1. Select `Diskimage` and browse to the ISO files location.
2. Make sure that the right USB drive is selected and then hit `OK`.

   [image]

This will create a bootable USB drive off the provided image.