# Invalid or damaged bootable partition

Tags: installation, boot, live-usb, iso

I downloaded Ubuntu from the Ubuntu website and copied it to a pen drive. On booting it I'm getting an error stating `Invalid or damaged bootable partition`. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: for Windows see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30048/how-can-i-create-a-bootable-usb-disk-from-a-cd-image