# I boot my usb and the copyrights details show but I cannot go anywhere from there?

Tags: boot, usb, configuration, live-usb, usb-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu from an USB drive / create a live USB-stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick)
>   [How can I create a bootable USB disk from a CD image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30048/how-can-i-create-a-bootable-usb-disk-from-a-cd-image)

I plug in my usb and turn my computer and then the copy rights come on the screen. It then says it cannot find  the configuration file and I cannot do anything from there on. It is important to note I did use the universal usb thing and this appeared after I sued that and tried to boot the usb. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please state more specifically what you are trying to do. It sounds like you are trying to install Ubuntu by using a live USB. Is this correct? And how do you get this error message? Black screen?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I am using a usb to install ubunta, I sued universal usb in order to install ubunta on the usb I think. I load up the computer with the usb in the proper spot and it loads up a black screen with copy rights which is fine but then it says it cannot find the configuration file and everytime I press enter after, it says the same thing

Comment: First things first, the name is **Ubuntu** not "ubunta", second: here you have instructions how to make a Live USB and how to boot from a Live USB [How do I install Ubuntu from a USB drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick)

Comment: The "copy rights" would be the BIOS logo screen.  My guess is that USB drive is not set up as a bootable device

Answer (score 0):

Try first plugging your USB into another computer and rename the folder "isolinux" to "syslinux" and the files "isolinux.bin" and "isolinux.cfg" in that folder to "syslinux.bin" and "syslinux.cfg" respectively. Then try booting with the USB again.

If that does not work, you will have to reformat your USB to FAT. You can do that using a tool like GParted ("sudo apt-get install gparted" in terminal). After that make the USB drive again and it should be fine.

Source: http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/syslinux-no-default-ui-error-fix.html