# Where can I get Project Looking Glass source code?

Tags: java, desktop-environments, svn, source-code

I came across Project Looking Glass while searching for different desktop managers. I saw a few previews and I would like to get it on 12.04.

The site from  [Project Looking Glass's Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Looking_Glass) ( http://java.net/projects/lg3d ) isn't working. I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29844/where-can-i-find-a-package-for-project-looking-glass-the-java-desktop) but the answer isn't working either. `svn` gives this error

> ved [ ~ ] >>>> svn co https://svn.java.net/svn/lg3d~svn
>   svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.java.net/svn/lg3d~svn': could not connect to server (https://svn.java.net)

Where do I get the source code for PLG?

**I want it out of pure interest in programming in Java and Linux.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code is still accessible in [the web-based SVN interface here](http://java.net/projects/lg3d/sources/svn/show).

Comment: The URL given in the interface is **exactly the same** as that in the question. Why wasn't it working earlier?

Comment: @VedVals (1) It's not the same at all. It's *similar* to the URL of the project page, and *quite dissimilar* to the URL you used in the `svn` command. (2) Besides that, you used remote SVN, and this method accesses the SVN repository through its web-based interface.

Comment: I don't understand, how can the same URL and the same svn command give different results? I used `svn co` which gave me the code now and it is  the same code and URL which gave me error earlier.

Comment: The URL you gave directs me to an interface to browse the code. There is an option to checkout the code which I used to get the code via svn. **That URL** is the same, not the link in the answer. I messed up the first comment. Sorry.

Comment: @VedVals Ah, I see. Assuming you entered it correctly the first time, my guess is that remote SVN access to the repository was down at the time you first tried, and then it came back online.

Comment: I had thought of that and did try a couple of days later. It still gave me the error so I had to ask for it here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the unfortunate answer is:

**You can't.**

PLG is *very* old, no longer maintained, and probably won't run on any modern system. Either way, you don't need it. There's Compiz, Kwin, Mutter, Gala... no need for PLG :).

Comment: My interest is w. r. t. the coding part. Actually I have about 20 entries for desktop managers while logging in. I wanted to study desktop managers and find Java easier to handle as compared to other languages hence my interest in PLG. I want the code, even if it is outdated.

Comment: @VedVals for the purpose of your intention, try something like RazorQt, not PLG. It's too outdated to be good for learning something like that.

Comment: To besides, there is a good reason no one develops desktops in Java. Apart from security issues, there is a problem of the overhead, lack of access to certain system features (without introducing too many dependencies to the code), etc.

Comment: I liked the circular application switching and the glassy look. How to get that?

Comment: @VedVals use KDE for the glassy look, use a dock and maybe write your own switcher to get the circular look.